# Stripping information from external webpage

Tags: javascript, iframe

[This page](http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly) lists the currently trending Google topics. I would like to extract this list using JavaScript.

I know it's theoretically possible using an `iframe` but there are complications with that approach (such as knowing when the `iframe` has loaded, using a separate instance of jQuery for that `iframe`).

Is there a better approach to the `iframe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you linked to is an ATOM feed which is basically an XML file. You can parse it/and or use however you like using something like [Google Feed API](https://code.google.com/apis/feed/). There is an example on how to use it [here](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=feeds#load_feed)

**EDIT :** here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZG5Gs/9/) that extracts the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for this. Despite my best efforts, though, I'm always getting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" with the example code they give. I got an API key, used the jQuery `.ready()`, etc. Could you provide a working jsfiddle, that would truly be awesome?

Comment: I don't have a working domain name to sign up for an API key. In the example I linked to in my answer, just replace this [link](http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml) with [this one](https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly) and it should work like a charm.

Comment: It doesn't! I'm getting this stupid error message. Here you go: ABQIAAAAd_V3IVF4bGjN54CKrdHD-xTqEUmM9CnW1gdZMF3lP075gpRXbBSFYUmm-siH3jDaCSDntT37tLmqLw

Comment: @Randomblue Sorry for the wait, I had some work to do. I updated my answer with a link to the jsfiddle.